# cómo actualizar la fuente de x-editable del tipo select2

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código donde cargo un listado de datos, pero quiero poder actualizar este listado si el usuario selecciona un `radio button`.

Debería crear una segunda función y ahí crear mi nuevo `array`?, debido a que la primera función tiene parámetros.

Espero haberme explicado bien

PD: Encontré este post pero no entiendí muy bien el código: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423115/how-to-update-the-source-of-x-editable-of-select2-type

Este es mi archivo `php` donde realizo la consulta al `ajax`.

```
$output   = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $output[]=$row;
    }
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

```js
$(function() {
  var pieza = [];
  function getData(Y) {
    $.ajax({
      data: {
        'Y': Y,
      },
      url: 'JSON/updateSource.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
       success: function(response) {
         $.each(response, function(k, v) {
        /* '"+v.item+"':'"+v.item+"',*/
         }, function(k, v) {
          pieza.push({
              value: k,
              text: v
          });
      });
      },
      async: false,
    });
  }
  
  $('#change_list').click(function(e){
   var x =  $(this).val();
    console.log(x);
});
 
  $('#table').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.task',
    title: 'task',
    type: "POST",
   /* source: getData(Y), Aqui deberia carga mi listado */
    showbuttons: true,
    type: 'select2',
    select2: {
      width: 500,
      placeholder: 'new item',
      allowClear: true
    },
    validate: function(value) {
      if ($.trim(value) == '') {
        return 'Empty!';
      }
    },
    success: function(response) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-check">
                 <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="ESPECIALES" id="change_list" name="check_list">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="materialGroupExample8">Códigos Especiales</label>
          </div>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td data-name="task" data-placement="bottom" class="task" data-type="select2">001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td data-name="task" data-placement="bottom" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿No debería ser un `checkbox` para que el usuario pueda volver al estado anterior?

Comment: haber si entendí, tienes un select(combobox) que se carga con ciertos datos, y tu deseas que al hacer clic en un radio button  o en un checkbox(alternativa) se actualice la información contenida en el select (combobox)?..

Comment: @Cesarin sii ahi un ejemplo en el link

Comment: @MoteCL Si esta un tanto complejo ese código,  como una alternativa viable podrías considerar que al momento que le den clic en radio, checbox o botón que pongas para este propósito, se bloqueara el select que muestras inicialmente y pusieras otro select que se active y muestre el contenido que deseas.  Es una idea

Answer (score 1):

Creo haberte entendido. Podrías programarle al `radio button` un evento `change`, es decir que cuando cambie su valor, se ejecute nuevamente la consulta que llena el `select`.

En el `HTML`

```
<input type="radio" onchange="myFunction()" id="change_list" value='false'/>
```

En el `JS`

```
function myFunction() {
  //Acá llamas a tu función de cargar el select nuevamente
}
```

El problema que le veo al `radio button` es que solo te funcionaría una única vez por lo que igual funcionaría con un botón pero con el evento `onclick`

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Actualizar</button>
```

Comment: necesito que se actualice la información contenida en el select